# What is the best appraoch to create an Arabic storeview including Arabic theme in magento?

Tags: magento, themes

I have magento site with two storeviews english and arabic. I have created a theme for English storeview(default storeview). Now I wanted to make Arabic storeview apprear in arabic.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not SO type of question, here is how this can be done:

If you have already created Arabic store view you need to find Arabic translation package either from [Magento site](http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations) or from [Magento connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=1&pl=0&te=0&q=arabic&t=1&p=1), download it and upload on your site in app/locale folder

After that you need to go to System -> Configuration, choose the needed store view and find Locale options section under General tab. Next, from Locale drop-down, select the right one (the first comes language, the second – country, for example, for Saudi Arabia Arabic it would be Arabic (Saudi Arabia)).

After refreshing caches, the store view can be accessed via _store=store_code">http://yoursite.com/index.php?_store=store_code. There is also a setting to add store_code into URL like this http://site.com/index.php/store_code. It can be set up in System -> Config -> Web -> Url Options -> Add Store Code to Urls.